# Database path cannot be converted in SQLiteAsyncConnection

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, xamarin

I'm learning how to create a local database on mobile devices by using SQLite.Net.Async. I'm following a tutorial step by step but something wrong with my database path. The error message says '**Argument 1 cannot convert from string to System.Func SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnectionWithLock'**. I was confused because this code works well on the tutorial sample.

This is my code:

```
using SQLite.Net.Async;

namespace ToDoList
{
    public class TodoItemDatabase
    {
        readonly SQLiteAsyncConnection asyncdatabase;

        public TodoItemDatabase (string dbPath)
        {
            asyncdatabase = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbPath);
            //I haven't done further because I was stucked by dbPath error
        }
    }
}
```

The sample code works well:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using SQLite;

namespace Todo
{
public class TodoItemDatabase
{
    readonly SQLiteAsyncConnection database;

    public TodoItemDatabase(string dbPath)
    {
        database = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbPath);
        database.CreateTableAsync<TodoItem>().Wait();
    }

    public Task<List<TodoItem>> GetItemsAsync()
    {
        return database.Table<TodoItem>().ToListAsync();
    }

    public Task<List<TodoItem>> GetItemsNotDoneAsync()
    {
        return database.QueryAsync<TodoItem>("SELECT * FROM [TodoItem] WHERE [Done] = 0");
    }

    public Task<TodoItem> GetItemAsync(int id)
    {
        return database.Table<TodoItem>().Where(i => i.ID == id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    }

    public Task<int> SaveItemAsync(TodoItem item)
    {
        if (item.ID != 0)
        {
            return database.UpdateAsync(item);
        }
        else {
            return database.InsertAsync(item);
        }
    }

    public Task<int> DeleteItemAsync(TodoItem item)
    {
        return database.DeleteAsync(item);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: the first thing I notice is that your working sample is using SQLite, while your non-working code is using SQLite.Net.Async

Comment: That was another issue. I tried using SQLite package before but it didn't work as well as the sample code. So after research on Google, I decided to use SQLite.Net.Async instead of SQLite, then it worked

Comment: So the working sample is using a completely different package than the non-working one?

Comment: Ok, I will take a try again. There are many packages on the package store sharing the same name.

Comment: Solved. I was trying to use SQLite-net PCL 1.3.1 at very beginning but I couldn't even install it successfully. So I installed another package having the similar package name, and it worked partly. After that, I used a old version of SQLite-net PCL 1.2.1, It worked !!

Comment: @JoeyZhang I am facing same issue on VS 2017 0n mac, I have installed SQLite-net PCL but didn't help me. Can you get out of me from this error ?

Answer (score 0):

This is the package which is been used in the sample application [sqlite-net-pcl](https://www.nuget.org/packages/sqlite-net-pcl/)